# Proving surjectivity & injectivity of the function repeat(Alphabets*) elegantly.

Tags: functions, proof-verification, proof-writing

Decide if function below is surjective, injective, both, or neither.

[image]

conc(w,w) as in 'w' + 'w' = 'ww'
Alph* = { ^, a,b,c...,y,z}
How do i prove this (elegantly/in 'math language')?

My attempt:

**It is injective.**

For all elements of codomain (in range Alph*), there is a unique input in the domain.
 Hence it is injective. (totally not convincing at all)

**It is not surjective.**

Given an odd length string such as 'www' in codomain, there is no element in domain that can be mapped to it.

Hence it is not surjective.

Answer (score 1):

I take it that the set $\text{Alph}^*$ consists of arbitrary length strings in the alphabet $\{a,\cdots,z\}$, and $\text{Repeat}$ simply takes a string, and concatenates it, with itself.

Then, $\text{Repeat}$ is injective. Indeed, we will write $a_i,b_j$ to mean an arbitary character in our alphabet. Then $\text{Repeat}(a_0\dots a_n)=\text{Repeat}(b_0\dots b_n)=a_0\dots a_n a_0\dots a_n=b_0\dots b_n b_0\dots b_n$, then $a_i=b_i$ for each $i\in \{1,\dots, n\}$, and hence this was the same string in $\text{Alph}^*$.

It fails to be surjective, since $ab$ is not mapped to by any element of $\text{Alph}^*$ by our map $\text{Repeat}$.